# How to move or backup symbol server?

Tags: c++, windows, symstore

I have been storing symbols for my builds on my local machine using the following command:

`call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\symstore.exe" add /r /f .\*.* /s "C:\Users\Sam\symbols" /t "Application" /v "rev %SVN_REVISION%" /c "adding revision %SVN_REVISION%"`

This has been working fine so far for debugging crashes. However now I want to make these available to other people on a central server I need to know how to move this symbol server. Just copying the folder doesn't work, there are some examples in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) however they seem to deal with moving pointers to the symbols and the example given:

`symstore add /y \\hubserver\hubshare\myindex.txt /g \\myarchive\appserver /s \\sampledir\symsrv /p /t "Large Application" /v "Build 432" /c "Sample Add from Index"`

is for moving a single entry when I want to move all of them.

I tried guessing at this syntax with:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\symstore.exe" /g C:\Users\Sam\symbols /s \\public\symbols`

But this wasn't a recognised command.

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer at https://www.wintellect.com/merging-symbol-servers/
The simplest case is just to create the new symbol server, and merge all the current files into it with something like:

```
symstore add /r /f \\Retiring\Share /s \\Combined\Share /t "Merging Symbol Servers"
```